# WordPress CF7 Add in

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-match, contact-form

For the upcoming GDPR i am creating a plugin that add some snippets to every site of my customers.

The code i now have problems with, should check if Contact Form 7 is installed and if a post with the post type 'wpcf7_contact_form' and the title 'Kontakt' exists. If so it should get the post content and check if a submit and an acceptance field exists. If there is a submit button but no acceptance field, it should concatenate the acceptance string (including the button shortcode) with the found submit part and replace it in the post content.

After some test i noticed that the check if there is a post and if cf7 is installed work. The rest isn´t. The preg_match patterns where created with http://www.phpliveregex.com/. I right now have no clue why it is not woking, thanks for any help in advance.

Edit: After some debugging(still in the code) i noticed, that now the check_submit and the check_acceptance functions do not work. The rest of the coe should now run.

The code:

```
<?php 

add_action( 'admin_init', 'init_cf7_privacy');
function init_cf7_privacy() {

    if ((check_cf7_installation()) && (find_contact_form() != "")) {

        $formContent = get_contactform_content();
        $acceptance = '[acceptance acceptance-842]<small>Ich habe die <a href="/datenschutzerklaerung">Datenschutzerklärung</a> zur Kenntnis genommen. Ich stimme zu, dass meine Angaben zur Kontaktaufnahme und für Rückfragen dauerhaft gespeichert werden. </small>[/acceptance]';

        if (check_cf7_installation()) 
            echo "CF7 Returned true!" . "\r\n";

        echo "CF Page ID: " . find_contact_form();

        if (check_submit( $formContent )) 
            echo "Submit Returned true!" . "\r\n";

        if (check_acceptance( $formContent )) 
            echo "Acceptance Returned true!" . "\r\n";

        //echo concatenate_acceptance_submit( $formContent, $acceptance ) . "\r\n";
        echo add_acceptance( $formContent, $acceptance );

        $my_post = array(
              'ID'           => find_contact_form(),
              'post_content' => add_acceptance( $formContent, $acceptance ) ,
        );

        // Update the post into the database
        wp_update_post( $my_post ); 

    }
}

function check_cf7_installation() {
    if (class_exists('wpcf7'))
        return true;
}

function find_contact_form() {
    $searchTitle = 'Kontakt';
    $page = get_page_by_title( $searchTitle, OBJECT, 'wpcf7_contact_form');

    return $page->ID;
}

function get_contactform_content() {
    $my_postid = find_contact_form();
    $post_object = get_post($my_postid);
    $content = $post_object->post_content;

    return $content;
}

function concatenate_acceptance_submit( $formContent, $acceptance ) {
    if( preg_match('/.+\[submit\s["].+["]\].+/', $formContent, $matches ) ) {
        return $acceptance . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . $matches[0];
    }
}

function check_submit( $formContent ) {
    if ( preg_match('/\[submit\s["].+["]\]/', $formContent) )
         return true;
}

function check_acceptance( $formContent ) {
    if ( preg_match('/\[acceptance\s.+\]/', $formContent) )
         return true;
}

function add_acceptance( $formContent, $acceptance ) {
    if ( check_submit( $formContent ) && !check_acceptance( $formContent ) ) {

        if ( preg_match('/.+\[submit\s["].+["]\].+/', $formContent, $matches) ) {

            $formContentRep = str_replace( $matches[0], concatenate_acceptance_submit( $formContent, $acceptance ), $formContent );

            return $formContentRep;

        }
    }
}
```

The successfully received post content and subject for the preg_match function:

```
<p>Ihr Name (Pflichtfeld)<br />    [text* your-name] </p>
<p>Ihre E-Mail-Adresse (Pflichtfeld)<br />
[email* your-email] </p>

<p>Betreff<br />
[text your-subject] </p>

<p>Ihre Nachricht<br />
[textarea your-message x3] </p>


<p class="submit">[submit "tohuwabohu"]</p>
```

Comment: After a lot of debugging, can someone tell me why
 if ( preg_match('/\[submit\s["].+["]\]/', $formContent) )
         return true; returns nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t know exactly why, but the wp_update_post() made the chek functions not work correctly. The following code with wpdb querys is now working:

```
<?php 

add_action( 'admin_init', 'init_cf7_privacy');
function init_cf7_privacy() {

    if ((check_cf7_installation()) && (find_contact_form() != "")) {

        $formContent = get_contactform_content();
        $acceptance = '[acceptance acceptance-842]<small>Ich habe die <a href="/datenschutzerklaerung">Datenschutzerklärung</a> zur Kenntnis genommen. Ich stimme zu, dass meine Angaben zur Kontaktaufnahme und für Rückfragen dauerhaft gespeichert werden. </small>[/acceptance]';

        /*
        if (check_cf7_installation()) 
            echo "CF7 Returned true!" . "\r\n";

        echo "CF Page ID: " . find_contact_form() . "\r\n";

        if (check_submit( $formContent )) 
            echo "Submit Returned true!" . "\r\n";

        if (check_acceptance( $formContent )) 
            echo "Acceptance Returned true!" . "\r\n";

        echo concatenate_acceptance_submit( $formContent, $acceptance ) . "\r\n";
        */

        add_acceptance( $formContent, $acceptance );

    }
}

function check_cf7_installation() {
    if (class_exists('wpcf7'))
        return true;
}

function find_contact_form() {
    $searchTitle = 'Kontakt';
    $page = get_page_by_title( $searchTitle, OBJECT, 'wpcf7_contact_form');

    return $page->ID;
}

function get_contactform_content() {
    $my_postid = find_contact_form();

    global $wpdb;
    $content = $wpdb->get_var( 
        $wpdb->prepare( "
            SELECT meta_value
            FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta
            WHERE post_id = %d
            AND meta_key = %s
            ",
           $my_postid, '_form' ) 
    );

    return $content;
}

function concatenate_acceptance_submit( $formContent, $acceptance ) {
    if( preg_match('/.+\[submit\s["].+["]\].+/', $formContent, $matches ) ) {
        return $acceptance . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . $matches[0];
    }
}

function check_submit( $formContent ) {
    if ( preg_match('/\[submit\s["].+["]\]/', $formContent) )
        return true;
}

function check_acceptance( $formContent ) {
    if ( preg_match('/\[acceptance\s.+\]/', $formContent, $matches) )
        return true;
}

function add_acceptance( $formContent, $acceptance ) {
    if ( check_submit( $formContent ) && !check_acceptance( $formContent ) ) {

        if ( preg_match('/.+\[submit\s["].+["]\].+/', $formContent, $matches) ) {

            $formContentRep = str_replace( $matches[0], concatenate_acceptance_submit( $formContent, $acceptance ), $formContent );

            //Write new Cotact Form Content to Database
            global $wpdb;    

            $wpdb->query(
                $wpdb->prepare( "
                    UPDATE ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta
                    SET meta_value = %s
                    WHERE post_id = %d
                    AND meta_key = %s
                    ", 
                    $formContentRep, find_contact_form(), '_form' )
            );

        }
    }
}
```